# Store a path in a variable and pass it as a Argument

Tags: shell, powershell, arguments

My script searches through a directory tree for 2 files. If it finds the file then it saves the path in a variable called `$filesToDelete`.

I would like to pass it as a argument for `eg C:/user/script.ps1 .\$filestoDelete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `script.ps1` must start with a *param section*:

```
Param
( 
    $FilesToDelete
)
```

Then you can pass the parameter using:

```
C:/user/script.ps1 -FilesToDelete $filesToDelete
```

Comment: okay i see, would it work if i have a argument for e.g out:'-filesToDelete $filesToDelete\outputfile.txt i tried it but it seems that it cannot find the path

Comment: Then you have to either, load the content first before passing it to your second script, or you have to load the file within your script (using the `Get-Content` cmdlet).

Comment: `Get-Content $FilesToDelete` it gives me back whats inside the file that was found instead of the path. I tried `Get-Content -Path` as well but it has the same result

Comment: I solved it by doing out: $fileToDelete + '\outfile.txt'